# best way to create user table when having more columns on it ? mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, database-normalization

I am developing a matrimonial website using  php & mysql.

I want to perform following Filters and Matches operations after storing users information :

```
Matches one user with other users with there : Age / Height , Religion, Mother Tongue, Community, Location, Education, Profession.

and filter by : Age / Height , Religion, Mother Tongue, Community, Location, Education, Profession, Marital Status,Country Living in,Profession Area,Profile Created by,Eating habits,Drinking habits.
```

I am big confusion with ‘user’ table ? I have to store a lot of information about user in my database as listed below

**CASE 1 :** (store in 2 tables only )

**User common details - tbl_user** :

```
tbl_user(name, email, user_phone, user_gender, user_dob, user_religion, user_caste, user_living, user_password, profile_created_by)
```

**User Extra information - tbl_user_ meta**  :

containing users :

1 Basic Details (Marital Status*, Mother Tongue, Eating Habits*…),

2 Education & Career details (Education*, Occupation*…),

3 Location details (Country*, State, city ,Citizenship),

4 Partner Preferences (Height, Eating Habits* ,Drinking Habits*, Smoking Habits*…),

5 About user (*about_you, msg…)

Planning to Store all these details in ‘**tbl_user_ meta**’  table below :

```
tbl_user_ meta(user_meta_id,user_id,meta_key,meta_value )
```

**CASE  2** : (store in 6 different  table)

```
tbl_user(user_id,user_fname...user_verified )

basic_details(user_id, Eating Habits,..)

educ_career_details(user_id, Education , Occupation,..)

location _details(user_id, Country, State, city ,Citizenship)

partner_details(user_id,  Height, Eating_ Habits...)

about_details(user_id,  *about_you, msg…)
```

**CASE  3 :** (store in one  table only)

Storing all details in one table ‘**user**’ only with adding all column on it?

**Which CASE is best for handling all records easily within whole website? or there are some other best way to do this ?**

Comment: It's an opinion-based question. Will depend on your data modeling.

Comment: It depends how you want to query your tables (e.g. will you want to order by country ? Filter by marital status ?) and how your system will evolve (how often do you add new "meta" fields?). Each solution has pros & cons.

Comment: i have listed all information about my database and website. in case of matrimonial website we have to store more information about users. i just asking which is best way to store user info in database.

Comment: yes all these filter will come in future like Filter  marital status,age, caste, sub-caste .

Comment: as all matrimonial website did , i want to implement all kind of functionality. why you guys thumbs down my question, i am in big confusion right now which way is best for me.

Comment: People downvote your question because there is no "best" way. Every way you are suggesting is "the best" in some circumstances, and "the worst" in others. If you want a good answer, consider editing your question to include more information about the context and narrow down the problem you are having (see my previous comment).

Comment: ok thanks @rlanvin, let me edit my question.

Comment: @amitgupta ok, take your time to make your question look good (pay attention to the formatting, at the moment it's not easy to read). And keep in mind that your question should not be about  *opinions*, it should be about *facts*.

Comment: @rlanvin is this editing ok? or i have to provide some more information. can you guide me in my scenario ?

Comment: @amitgupta It's a bit better, but still not great. You are still asking for the "best" way. There is no best way, it's entirely a matter of *opinion*. My advice: pick any solution you want, implement it, and then if you have a specific problem that you cannot solve by yourself, come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: then i should delete this question ? coz people down voting this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88121/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-rlanvin).

Answer (score 1):

Better use **CASE 2** since in matrimonial site there so many search you may need to provide. in educ_career _details table store only education details by connecting education master table.

Comment: ok and whether i should store some information which is not usefull for search operations in user_meta table or not

Comment: you can, but it depends upon the information u storing, better to keep information which not showing in search,listing are in one table

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion question and can have many answers. If you have data that is always needed, while some of it is needed less often, than I would split the data into multiple tables; keeping the frequently accessed data in the main table and the less frequently accessed data in the support/meta tables.

Comment: *This is an opinion question and can have many answers* -- but should have **none** since it doesn't fit [SO question profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, I didn't know that it shouldn't be answered, I just wanted to give him a direction.

Comment: i want some  opinions so that i can finalize my way of working and could take any design.

Comment: @amitgupta - StackOverflow isn't the place to solicit opinions for something like this, where it's subjective and having no right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is better Case 2, but you have several mistakes in that case. For example with the user information i would use the following normalization:

```
person (idPerson, name,gender,religion,idUserProfile)
email (idEmail, email, idPerson)
phone (idPhone, phone, idPerson)
userProfile (idUserProfile, userProfile, password)
```

and so on.
¡Remember to ensure the password security!